# Listing my youtube videos in web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-dotnet-client

I can get my list of youtube videos using google .NET client libraries following the example in the following link

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

This works fine when I am using it in a console application and my project's Client Id is of type 'Installed Application'.

I want to make it work for my web application. I created a client id of type 'Web Application' and provided appropriate redirect_uri. When I run the application, it always generates a random redirect_uri in the request and I am getting redirect_uri mismatch error. How can I fix this problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions on https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications?
It contains code snippets and explanations about the 'redirect URI' you need to register in Google Developers Console (The URI should look like: your_site/AuthCallback/IndexAsync).

If you choose to create a ASP.NET (NOT MVC) application, you can take a look in the following sample: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg%2FTasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2.

Comment: Thank you so much. Following article I think written by you is more clear
http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2014/01/aspnet-mvc-with-google-openid-and-oauth.html

Comment: Do I need the DRIVE api in order to log in. I am looking at accessing YouTube playlists myself.